# Is there an alternative function to get a world map in R

Tags: r, maps, spatial

I'm currently using countriesSP <- getMap(resolution='low') from rworldmap but this package has now been depreciated. Is there a new way to get a spatial polygon map from a different package. Alternatively all I really need is a way to identify the country from a set of decimal coordinates. Is there an easier way to do this?

I have tried

```
`countriesSP <- ne_countries(
scale = 10,
type = "countries",
continent = NULL,
country = NULL,
geounit = NULL,
sovereignty = NULL,
returnclass = c("sp", "sf")
```

)`

but there are also removing the sp option in a future release and I don't know how to use the sf version.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `ggplot2::map_data("world")` may offer what you are looking for, see the documentation [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/map_data.html).

Look at the examples on that page and see if that looks about right.

Comment: Thanks for the response, do you know how to convert this into a sf object?

Answer (score 0):

If you need an `sp` object, you can always start with an `sf` and convert it to `sp` yourself. That's actually what's happening in the current version of `rnaturalearth::ne_countries()` when you ask it to return `sp`.

```r
library(sp)
# get sf object from ne_countries, convert to sp with {sf}:
countriesSP <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(returnclass = "sf") |> sf::as_Spatial()
summary(countriesSP[,1:4])
#> Object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
#> Coordinates:
#>    min       max
#> x -180 180.00000
#> y  -90  83.64513
#> Is projected: FALSE 
#> proj4string : [+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs]
#> Data attributes:
#>   featurecla          scalerank       labelrank      sovereignt       
#>  Length:177         Min.   :1.000   Min.   :2.000   Length:177        
#>  Class :character   1st Qu.:1.000   1st Qu.:3.000   Class :character  
#>  Mode  :character   Median :1.000   Median :3.000   Mode  :character  
#>                     Mean   :1.011   Mean   :3.712                     
#>                     3rd Qu.:1.000   3rd Qu.:5.000                     
#>                     Max.   :3.000   Max.   :7.000
plot(countriesSP)
```

[image]